# Optimize nested for-loops in terms of execution time

Tags: python, pandas

I want to optimize my code in terms of execution time. The code runs on the dataframe `alldata` that contains around 300,000 entries, but the computation takes a very long time (around 10 hours or so).

The logic of the computation is the following:

For each missing (nan) value of dataframe's columns specified in the list `list_of_NA_features`, the function `fill_missing_values` searches the most similar row (the Cosine similarity is computed based on columns in the list `list_of_non_nan_features` that are never empty) and returns the value of the current column and row in `alldata`.

```
from scipy import spatial

def fill_missing_values(param_nan,current_row,df):
    df_non_nan = df.dropna(subset=[param_nan])
    list_of_non_nan_features = ["f1","f2","f3","f4","f5"] 
    max_val = 0
    searched_val = 0
    vector1 = current_row[list_of_non_nan_features].values
    for index, row in df_non_nan.iterrows():
        vector2 = row[list_of_non_nan_features].values
        sim = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(vector1, vector2)
        if (sim>max_val):
            max_val = sim
            searched_val = row[param_nan]
    return searched_val


list_of_NA_features = df_train.columns[df_train.isnull().any()]


for feature in list_of_NA_features:
    for index,row in alldata.iterrows():
        if (pd.isnull(row[feature]) == True):
            missing_value = fill_missing_values(feature,row,alldata)
            alldata.ix[index,feature] = missing_value
```

Is it possible to optimize the code? For instance, I am thinking about the substitution of `for` loops with `lambda` functions. Is it possible?

Comment: How would making your for-loops `lambda` functions help? And why `lambda` functions instead of normal functions?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's my assumption, because I was reading that `apply(lambda x: ...)` is faster than for loop.

Comment: It is *certainly not*. `pandas.DataFrame.apply` is a python for-loop under the hood.

Comment: Can you express the data as a NumPy array and use a sample data? NumPy could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of substituting your for-loops with `lambdas`, try substituting them with [ufuncs.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html)

[Losing Your Loops: Fast Numerical Computation with Numpy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEUXKG97YRw) is an excellent talk by Jake Vanderplass on the subject.
Using universal functions and broadcasting instead of for-loops can dramatically improve the speed of your code.

Here is a basic example:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

def timed(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        t0 = time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed = time()-t0
        print(f'ran {func.__name__} in {elapsed} seconds)')
        return result
    return inner
# without broadcasting:

@timed
def sums():
    sums = np.zeros([500, 500])
    for a in range(500):
        for b in range(500):
            sums[a, b] = a+b
    return sums

@timed
def sums_broadcasted(): 
    a = np.arange(500)
    b = np.reshape(np.arange(500), [500, 1])
    return a+b
```

INPUT:

```
sums()
sums_broadcasted()
assert (a==b).all()
```

OUTPUT:

```
ran sums in 0.030008554458618164 seconds
ran sums_broadcasted in 0.0005011558532714844 seconds
```

Note by eliminating our loops we have a 60x speedup!